# How to use an ActiveX in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, activex

I have the following code in JavaScript that is working correctly

```
var ocx = undefined;
ocx = new ActiveXObject("namespace.class");
```

I am trying to use it in c #, as follows

```
namespace.class objectOcx = null;
objectOcx = namespace.class();
```

it returns the following error

> Error CS1955  Non-invocable member 'class' cannot be used like a method.

comment: the ocx is registered, it was added as reference to the application

What can be the error, or if there is another way to use the ocx?

Thank you very much in advance

**UPDATE**
Sorry for the writing error

```
namespace.class objectOcx = null;
objectOcx = new namespace.class();
```

> Error CS1729  'class' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Comment: `new`? `Activator.CreateInstance`?

Comment: @MarcGravell I have changed the code for `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(class));`, but it is returning the following error **System.MissingMethodException: 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.'**